# Intel Core going faster than even the Turbo Boost Max speed?

Tags: intel-core-i5

I have an Intel Core i5-4200U at 1.6GHz, with a maximum Turbo Boost of 2.6GHz. However, in Windows 8.1's task manager sometimes the current speed is going as high as 2.7GHz! How is this possible? I'm a bit worried because sometimes the computer goes overly loud when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different algorithms are used to measure processor speed. For example, the algorithm used by Intel in its branded maximum speed is different than the algorithm used by Task Manager to directly measure the speed of the CPU. You can use other processor utilities, such as the Intel Processor Identification Utility or CPU-Z, for additional processor speed measurements.

So what you are seeing is likely a difference in calculation method – Windows is not running the CPU over the recommended frequency (unless you are manually overclocking the CPU within the BIOS/UEFI settings).